# python3 bytes string encoding

Tags: python-3.4, python-unicode

i have this code:

```
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

doc = xmltodict.parse(data)

risultati = doc['result']['data']

mieiris = json.loads(risultati)

for k in mieiris['Headword']['Component']:
    try:
        print(k['Text'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        uhm = k['Text'].encode("utf-8")
        print(uhm.decode("unicode_escape"))
```

that returns me this result:

```
b'ci\xc3\xa0-o'
inter.
si usa come saluto amichevole e confidenziale quando ci si incontra o ci si lascia
b'Dal ven. {\\i s{#c-v-r#}iao}, propr. \xe2\x80\x98(sono vostro) schiavo\xe2\x80\x99'
```

now: I can't figure out how to properly display the last string with utf-8 encoding. Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: This all seems very unnecessary - you should only be getting `UnicodeEncodeError` if your console's locale can't (or thinks it can't) support the character you're printing.  You should either fix your console or write to a file instead. Your final `encode()` / `decode()` is totally crazy. This sounds like a typical X-Y problem

Comment: Hi @AlastairMcCormack, yes, it's totally crazy ;) I've done a lot of trials in order to obtain the string formatted in a proper way and that was my last one ;) I can't write to a file and this will be a telegram bot so the console won't be my final output.

Comment: :) ok, so you're working around a problem for a limitation in your specific console that won't exist in your final app - that's a bad idea :) Are you writing your own telegram bot (not sure how UTF-8 can be expressed in morse) or someone else's? As it stands, it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: I've found that module 'uniencode' solves my problem :) Anyway I am writing a  [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) bot. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved with unidecode module.

So my last for is now:

```
for k in mieiris['Headword']['Component']:
    try:
        print(k['Text'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print(unidecode(k['Text']))
```

Hope that this will help someone else :)